# VLAN support with a regular ISP router

Tags: router, switch, vlan

I'm considering getting a [NETGEAR GS308E](https://www.netgear.com/business/wired/switches/plus/gs308e/) switch which has VLAN support in order to create two VLANs for my home network: one VLAN for the work PC and another one for the rest of my personal devices. I don't need any communication between the two VLANs, just Internet connection.

However, my router is a regular ISP router (a [SerComm H500-s](http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/SerComm_H500-s) specifically) and I have not found any sign of VLAN support/compatibility on it. Will the VLAN configuration of the switch work in that case? If not, would it work with a layer 3 switch or would it make no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SerComm H500-s does not recognise VLANS (and I would not expect most SOHO routers would), then getting a layer 3 switch will not make any positive difference - I doubt the VLAN functionality will work.

That said, per your link, this device MIGHT work with OpenWRT - if you can get OpenWRT or DD-WRT on it you can likely get VLAN support working if you are using an Ethernet connection for your ISP.